# Msbuild failed when processing the file 'FILE LOCATION' with message: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found

Tags: c#, msbuild, sdk, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn to take an object, then explore the entire solution and find where it is declared. That part of the code has not even been started because I can't properly set up my workspace. My code is as follows:

```
var projectPath = @"C:\Repo\Pineapple\Pineapple.sln";
            using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
            {
                workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
                var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(projectPath).Result;
                ImmutableList<WorkspaceDiagnostic> diagnostics = workspace.Diagnostics;
                foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.Message);
                }

                foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
                {
                    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(project.Name + "\t\t\t" + document.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The second set of foreach loops had originally turned up empty prompting me to explore the diagnostics. The error message I received is listed in the title and was displayed for all files I tried to access. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Core 3.1. If it's not already obvious, I'm relatively new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried to run `nuget restore` on the `Pineapple.sln`?

Comment: I have. Unfortunately, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know much about the project you are trying to load, I've used instead [Nodatime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) and I've managed to load it successfully with your snippet by doing the following changes:

- Add a reference the `Microsoft.Build.Locator` NuGet package
- Call `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();` before creating the `MSBuildWorkspace`

Once I've done the above steps I had to add references also to these NuGet packages:

- NuGet.Frameworks
- NuGet.Packaging
- NuGet.ProjectModel
- NuGet.Versioning